# How to change Firefox installation path?

Tags: windows, firefox, path, installer

Have 2 SSDs in my PC, one for OS and one for applications to improve performance. However some programs (such as Firefox) are quite annoying. You download and run the installer and it automatically installs immediately without any options to hard-drive C: (or hard-drive where windows is) 
and grants no possibility to change the path.

Is there some hacky or less hacky solution to freely choose the installation-path without modifying all entries in the registry which is quite dangerous?

Comment: Do you want to move an existing install? Or choose a directory for a fresh install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mozilla Support [Custom installation of Firefox on Windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/custom-installation-firefox-on-windows) (I'll copy most of the instructions here for context and completeness):

- Download the full, offline Firefox installer for Windows (Firefox Setup .exe file) from the Advanced install options & other platforms link on the [Firefox download page](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=support.mozilla.org) or, if you wish to choose the language, from the [Download Firefox in your language](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/all/) page.
- When you run the full, offline installer, the Mozilla Firefox Setup Wizard will open.

[image]

- After clicking <kbd>Next</kbd> you can choose a Standard or Custom installation. The Standard setup will be selected by default.

[image]

- A Custom setup lets you choose the folder where Firefox program files will be installed, as well as which shortcuts to create. These options are not available in a Standard setup. Select the Custom setup type and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
- The next step is where you can choose a different Destination Folder, which is where the Firefox program will be installed.

[image]

- C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ is the default folder path on 32-bit Windows. It's also the default location on 64-bit Windows when the 64-bit Firefox version is installed.

  When the 32-bit Firefox version is installed on 64-bit Windows, the default folder path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\

  You can change the folder where Firefox will be installed either by manually typing the location of another folder on your computer or you can click <kbd>Browse...</kbd> to select a new folder.

From there there are also additional options you can select.

Comment: Your answer is better, so I've deleted mine.

Comment: Ok, a more more complete answer then I needed because im not a noob but I simply didnt knew an offline installer with custom options still exists. Thanks!